# How to get Tb Mega Menu working in Chrome?

Tags: navigation

I have a website and integrated Tb Mega Menu for the navigation. But the problem is my dropdown is not working in Google Chrome, though it is perfectly working in Internet Explore, Mozilla. My version of Google Chrome is 45.0.2454.85 m.

How to solve this issue? I did search for this, but found nothing suitable.

Answer (score -1):

After so much time I found an answer. I Just increase the z-index for that li and the dropdown start working for me.